# Error en petición GET con request en java

Tags: java, laravel, http, get

Estoy realizando una petición GET desde java, pero esta petición puede recibir un Request, he probado la api en postman y va de maravilla, pero al hacerlo desde java me arroja este problema:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 0 [character 1 line 1]

Mi código en *Laravel* es el siguiente:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    
    $campo=$request->input('campo');
    $valor=$request->input('valor');
    $campo2=$request->input('campo2');
    $valor2=$request->input('valor2');
    $campoOrden=$request->input('campoOrden');
    $tipoOrden=$request->input('tipoOrden');

    if(strlen($campo2)>0){
        $respuesta[]=CatalogoTruper::where($campo,$valor)
        ->where($campo2,$valor2)
        ->first();
    }else{
        if(strlen($campoOrden)){
            $respuesta[]=CatalogoTruper::where($campo,$valor)
            ->orderBy($campoOrden,$tipoOrden)
            ->first();
        }else{
            $respuesta[]=CatalogoTruper::where($campo,$valor)
        ->first();
        }
        
        
    }

    return json_encode($respuesta,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    
}
```

Y mi código en *JAVA* es el siguiente:

```
public String[] filaConsulta(String tabla,String columna,String valor,String extra) {
    String [] ordenCampos=ord.Orden(tabla);
    
    String resul="";
    String msg;
    
    
    
    StringBuilder resultado=new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url= new URL(urlString+tabla);
        Map <String, Object> params=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        
        
            params.put("campo",columna);
            params.put("valor", valor);
            if(extra.length()>0){
                String orden[]=extra.split(" ");
                params.put("campoOrden",orden[0]);
                params.put("tipoOrden",orden[1]);   
            }
            
        
        
        StringBuilder postData= new StringBuilder();
        //postData.append("?");
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            
            if(postData.length()!=0) 
                postData.append('&');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(),"utf-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()),"UTF-8"));
                
                
            }
            byte[] postDataBytes=postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(postData.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
            
            BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            
            String linea;
            
            while ((linea=rd.readLine())!=null){
                resultado.append(linea+"\n");
            }
            
            rd.close();
            resul=resultado.toString();
            JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(resul);
            
                JSONObject obj= jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String[] registros=new String[ordenCampos.length];
                
                for(int i=0;i<ordenCampos.length;i++) {
                    
                    registros[i]=""+obj.get(ordenCampos[i]);
                    
                }
                
        return registros;
    
    } catch (MalformedURLException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

La respuesta de JSON que es el resultado de una consulta a partir del request es como el siguiente:

```
[{"idCatalogoTruper":10911,"codigoProducto":22606,"codigoBarra":"7501206644812","clave":"218-P","descripcion":"Pinza pesada de electricista 8',Pretul","caja":6,"master":36,"unidad":"Pieza","precioPublico":147,"precioPublicoSI":126.719999999999998863131622783839702606201171875,"precioMayoreo":126,"precioMayoreoSI":108.6200000000000045474735088646411895751953125,"precioSubdistribuidor":115,"precioSubdistribuidorSI":99.1400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625,"precioDistribuidor":105,"precioDistribuidorSI":90.5199999999999960209606797434389591217041015625,"marca":"Pretul","codigoSAT":"27112105","descripcionSAT":"Pinzas"}]
```

> **Nota:** El JSON en el campo de marca me devuelve el valor sin las comillas de inicio así :Pretul" y no "Pretul" y este JSON se puedo obtener a partir de POSTMAN.

Lo he probado en localhost y en un hosting pero aun nada, no logro entender si no entrada en la función show de *Laravel*, anteriormente intentaba hacerlo con un request y una variable pero me arrojaba un el error 405, decidí meter todo en el Request pero ahora tengo este problema.

Comment: Podrías mostrar el JSON de la respuesta que devuelve tu API de laravel?

Comment: claro, ya edite la pregunta y puse una observación de la que no me había dado percatado, puede influir esa comilla?, muchas gracias por comentar.

Comment: Disculpa, cuando dices "La respuesta de JSON es como el siguiente:" te refieres a que el JSON que pegaste no es exactamente el que recibes desde postman? Si ese es el caso, te voy a pedir que pegues exactamente el JSON que recibes y no algo parecido.

Comment: el json es el resultado de una consulta, ese que pegue es el ejemplo una consulta hecha con los resultados de un request

Comment: A lo que voy, por favor agrega el JSON real que es el que te está dando problemas. De otra manera no podremos ayudarte. La excepción que obtienes "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 0 [character 1 line 1]" se debe al JSON recibido en Java, si pegas otro JSON que no es el que recibes, entonces no sabremos cual puede ser el error.

Comment: Es que el JSON se genera a partir del request que se envía, el que puse es uno que hice en postman, enviando una request, ahora en java cuando trato enviar ese request me genera esa excepción, entiendo que es del lado de java, que no esta enviando nada y por tal motivo el JSON de respuesta ha de ser algo asi: [][]. espero explicarme.

Comment: El JSON es ese, pero, desde java al hacer la petición, no envía los parámetros que se necesitan, entonces, regresa un JSON vacío [][].